# Web-scraping. Columns instead of rows

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have difficulties scraping data and saving it to a consistent columns. 
More specifically, the website I scrape does not have a separate tags for each and every item I scrape (except key and value).

As a result, I get a CSV file with 2 rows - key and value and corresponding text in them, whereas my idea is to get columns instead.

Is it possible to keep headers constant and append value items or it is not possible, given the specifics of the website?

Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

keys = []
values = []

for pagenumber in range (0,2):
        url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/p/'
        txt = requests.get(url+str(pagenumber))
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt.text, 'html.parser')
        soup_table = soup.find('ul', 'mp-Listings mp-Listings--list-view')

        for car in soup_table.findAll('li'):
            link = car.find('a')
            sub_url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/' + link.get('href')

            sub_soup = requests.get(sub_url)
            soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sub_soup.text, 'html.parser')
            soup1 = soup1.find('div', {'id': 'car-attributes'})

            for car_item in soup1.findAll('div', {'class': 'spec-table-item'}):

                    key = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'key'}).text
                    keys.append(key)

                    value = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'value'}).text
                    values.append(value)


auto_database = pd.DataFrame({
                               'key': keys,
                               'value': values,
                              })

auto_database.to_csv('auto_database.csv')
print("Successfully saved..")
```

**Results**

```
Merk & Model: Lako
Bouwjaar: 1996
Uitvoering: 233 C
Carrosserie: Open wagen
Kenteken: OD-31-VD
APK tot: 29 juni 2020
Prijs: € 7.500,00


Merk & Model: RAM
Bouwjaar: 2020
Carrosserie: SUV of Terreinwagen
Brandstof: LPG
Kilometerstand: 70 km
Transmissie: Automaat
Prijs: Zie omschrijving
Motorinhoud: 5.700 cc
Opties:
```

**Wanted result**

```
Merk & Model    Bouwjaar
RAM              2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to save all metadata per car item to a dataframe, set the keys as the index and join all intermediate dataframes to a final one.

Try this:

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

frames = []

for pagenumber in range (0,2):
        url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/p/'
        txt = requests.get(url+str(pagenumber))
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt.text, 'html.parser')
        soup_table = soup.find('ul', 'mp-Listings mp-Listings--list-view')

        for car in soup_table.findAll('li'):

            link = car.find('a')
            sub_url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/' + link.get('href')

            sub_soup = requests.get(sub_url)
            soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sub_soup.text, 'html.parser')
            soup1 = soup1.find('div', {'id': 'car-attributes'})

            tmp = []

            for car_item in soup1.findAll('div', {'class': 'spec-table-item'}):

                key = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'key'}).text
                value = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'value'}).text
                tmp.append([key, value])

            frames.append(pd.DataFrame(tmp).set_index(0))


df_final = pd.concat((tmp_df for tmp_df in frames), axis=1, join='outer').reset_index()
df_final = df_final.T
df_final.columns = df_final.loc["index"].values
df_final.drop("index", inplace=True)
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_final.to_csv('auto_database.csv')
display(df_final.head(3))
```

Output:

```
Bouwjaar:   Brandstof:  Kilometerstand:     Transmissie:    Prijs:  Motorinhoud:    Kenteken:   Opties:     Merk & Model:   Carrosserie:    Uitvoering:     APK tot:    Energielabel:   Verbruik:   Topsnelheid:    Kosten p/m:     Vermogen:   APK:    Datum van registratie:
0   2014    Diesel  10.000 km   Automaat    € 10.950,00     400 cc  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2011    Diesel  25.000 km   Handgeschakeld  Op aanvraag     1.500 cc    VR-921-X    \n\nParkeersensor\nMetallic lak\nBoordcomputer...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   2016    Benzine     95.545 km   Handgeschakeld  € 230,00    1.395 cc    NaN     \n\nParkeersensor\nMetallic lak\nRadio\nMistla...   A3  Sedan   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciated your input!

Comment: @Iva You're welcome.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you one more time. I want to run another loop for place.      
  `soup2 = sub_soup_txt.find('div', {'id': 'vip-seller'})

            for car_item in soup2.findAll('ul', {'class': 'seller-info-links'}):
                place = car_item.find('h3', {'class':'heading'}).text.strip()
                tmp.append([place])`                                                                                          However, this yields to a shift in the database. Is it possible to append place data as well somehow?

Comment: Your code snippet unfortunately doesn't run. `NameError: name 'sub_soup_txt' is not defined`. Can I suggest you post this as a new question and provide the current code that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

cars = []

for pagenumber in range (0,2):
        url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/p/'
        txt = requests.get(url+str(pagenumber))
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt.text, 'html.parser')
        soup_table = soup.find('ul', 'mp-Listings mp-Listings--list-view')

        for car in soup_table.findAll('li'):
            link = car.find('a')
            sub_url = 'https://www.marktplaats.nl/' + link.get('href')

            sub_soup = requests.get(sub_url)
            soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sub_soup.text, 'html.parser')
            soup1 = soup1.find('div', {'id': 'car-attributes'})

            attribs = {}
            for car_item in soup1.findAll('div', {'class': 'spec-table-item'}):
                    key = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'key'}).get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
                    value = car_item.find('span', {'class': 'value'}).get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
                    attribs[key] = value
            cars.append(attribs)

unique_keys = set(k for car in cars for k in car.keys())
data = [{k: car.get(k) for k in unique_keys} for car in cars]

auto_database = pd.DataFrame(data)
auto_database.to_csv('auto_database.csv')
print("Successfully saved..")
```

Produces this csv file (screenshot from Libre Office):

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrej! Thank you very much for you input!